# Inconsistent behaviour of conf.setLocale()

Tags: android, locale

As per the given [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/5754623), I'm using the following code to change the language programmatically:

```
       DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
       Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            conf.setLocale(newLocale);
        } else {
            conf.locale = newLocale;
        }
       res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

I'm calling this in `onCreate()` in each activity before `setContentView()` and after `super.Oncreate()`.

`conf.setLocale()` internally calls `setLayoutDirection()` and is supposed to change the layout direction according to the specified `locale`. But it's behaviour is not consistent. The layout direction gets overridden by the system frequently. What should be the workaround for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that obtaining resources with Application's `context` were causing this inconsistent behaviour. Using `getResources()` from the activity instead resolves the problem.